# How do I close a socket or an I/O Stream in the windowClosing event of a Java window?

Tags: java, sockets, iostream

I'm having trouble closing my socket when exiting my Java application. I thought that an easy way to make sure the socket gets closed is to hook it on windowClosing in a Swing JFrame like this:

```
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            input.close();
            output.close();
            socket.close();

            frame.dispose();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
```

But then I have to handle the IOException that close() creates, and I can't throw it when overriding the event method like that.

How can I make sure that my streams and my socket get closed when the program does?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to throw it. Just catch it.

```
try {
  if(null != input) {
    input.close();
  }
} catch(IOException ex) {
  // Log or ignore the exception.
}
```

Also, you don't need to call the dispose() or System.exit(0); methods if your main application Frame is already closing.

Make sure that the following is set on your main Application JFrame.

```
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: When I catch the exception like that, the window doesn't close. It just sits and I have to kill the run from the IDE. Also, the socket still doesn't close. Not sure how I can make this work.

Comment: You must set the following on your main Application Frame.
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't block the event dispatch thread -- the close() methods might block in some cases.

Comment: How would I tell if it blocks? And if it does, how can I prevent it?
Thanks.

Comment: It may depend on the environment.  For example on the blackberry close() methods may block for 2 minutes.  So (as bad as it sounds) the fix was to spawn a thread just to close the sockets!

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem by catching the IOException, as S73417H said, and making sure to close the streams in this order: output, input, socket. Thanks to everyone who answered.

Comment: Keep in mind closing the Socket closes the input and output streams on its own, you're doing extra work.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a forum. You should delete this post and instead accept the answer you found most helpful.